# Will messages delivered as SMS if I'm blocked in iMessage?

Tags: ios, messages, sms

I texted somebody on iMessage but I think the recipient blocked me. iMessage says it got sent as a normal text. Will that text go to the recipient's phone?

Answer (score 2):

If she has blocked you, then the message will not be sent to her.

When you first send a message to another Apple device, it will look like an `iMessage`. It will then change to look like an `SMS` message, just like you experienced. To you, it will look like a regular message, and it will look like it sent, but she will not actually receive it.